# I'm using the same model twice in my code, how to avoid transferring weights?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm using same tensorflow model twice in my Colab notebook. I want it to start learning all over again, but it's using previous weights. What is the way to avoid it? I have to null model's weights somehow. How can I do that?
That is how I define my model

```
input_img = Input((height, width, 1), name='img')
model = get_unet(input_img, n_filters=16, dropout=0.05, batchnorm=True)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss="mean_squared_error")
```

Comment: Add code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you define the model, save it. Then when you want to reset the weights, load the weights of the initial model.

```
input_img = Input((height, width, 1), name='img')
model = get_unet(input_img, n_filters=16, dropout=0.05, batchnorm=True)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss="mean_squared_error")
model.save_weights('init_model.h5')

#train train train

#now reset
model.load_weights('init_model.h5')
```